# Milling Machine tools running Windows XP are unable to open or save files to Windows 2019 SMB1.0 file share

Tags: windows

we have some pretty old Windows XP controlled milling machines (HURCO's).
Until recently they were accessing their program files (XML based) from a Windows Server 2012R2 file share.

The physical server the share is located on, is to be decommissioned, so I've copied the data to a Windows Server 2019 VM with the SMB1.0 feature installed.

Since changing the machine tools to point their mapped drives to the new Windows 2019 server, they've been experiencing difficulties accessing their programs, getting a fairly generic "operating system error". If I look at one of the programs they are trying to open / save over and try and change the filename or delete it from the server I get an error telling me the program is in use by "System".

If I check in Open Files I can see (this time but not always) the file is opened for read (at least twice) with no locks against it.

I appreciate this is pretty obscure but I'm at a loss to know how to proceed.

We can't upgrade the Machine tools operating system as it would cost £1000's

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Upgrade the OS. Working around more and more incompatibilities will cost you even more £ in the long run, and a lot more when you take unpatched security issues into account.

Comment: For that cost I would update the machine, I would understand for like CT Scan machine, that got an XP in it, that it's near impossible to upgrade, as the gear itselft cost like 1m$, but if you got the option at that cost to upgrade, dont miss it.

Comment: Agreed, the time you spend trying to keep this antique OS running will cost more than that!

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions but I'm never going to swing a suggestion to upgrade the OS on the milling machines when the problem only started when the data was moved to another server. These machines are central to the business and it's just not an option to upgrade them. I'm not even sure they can be upgraded.

Comment: Then your better move imo is to pop a old server vm to server those XP, like a 2012R2.

Comment: Took your advice Yahmoth555 so far so good !